# regex match file with multiple extension

Tags: regex, filenames

I have several strings like this

**XYZ_TEST_2017.txt**

**ASD_TEST_2017.txt.tmp**

I need to extract only those strings ending with .txt

So I'm using this regex:

```
[A-Z]{3}_TEST_[0-9]{4}.txt
```

However I still get the strings with multiple extensions like the second one (.txt.tmp)

[See my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l1CG2B/1).

How can I handle it?

Comment: Put a `$` at the end of your pattern: `[A-Z]{3}TEST[0-9]{4}\.txt$`

Comment: Thank you, it works

Comment: @Psi: Why not add an answer?

Comment: Right, why not an answer... Writing that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your regex match everything up to the end, append an "end-of-text marker" (`$`) to your pattern like this:

```
[A-Z]{3}_TEST_[0-9]{4}\.txt$
```

As you may have noticed, I also escaped the dot, otherwise this filename would match as well:

```
SOM_TEST_1234Etxt
```

The dot (`.`) would match *any* character (depending on your flags, even newline and carriage return), in this case, the `E` before `txt`.